# Why do I get a run error handling custom error types in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a problem with handing my errors using `.expect()`.
Here is my code:

**src/main.rs**

```
mod myerrors;

fn main() {
    mytest().expect("incorrrect number");
    //let shows: Vec<Show> = download().expect("read error");
    //print(shows);
}

fn mytest() -> std::result::Result<i8, myerrors::MyError>
{
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut line: String = String::new();
    match stdin.read_line(&mut line)
    {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(_) => return Err(myerrors::DownloadError),
    };
    let num: i8 = match line.parse::<i8>()
    {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => return Err(myerrors::MyError),
    };
    return Ok(num);
}
```

**src/myerrors.rs**

```
pub struct MyError;

impl std::fmt::Debug for MyError
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result
    {
        f.debug_struct("DownloadError").finish()
    }
}
```

It builds, but crashes after any input with **thread 'main' panicked at 'incorrrect number: DownloadError', src/main.rs:4:14**.

Comment: `line.parse::<i8>()` is returning an error. `.expect` tries to unwrap the result, but panics because it is an error. This is expected behaviour with `.expect`. The problem lies withing your code logic, not with error handling

Comment: what is your input and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed I fixed that but the same error remains

Comment: @kmdreko even if I input "123" I am getting panic error in main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is .expect() causing the program to panic?

The short answer is that if the `Result` is `Ok`, then `.expect()` will unwrap and return the contained value in the `Ok` tuple struct. If the `Result` is `Err`, then `.expect()` will panic with the message you specified.

In your case it appears that one of your `Err(_)` values is being returned by `mytest()`, and so the `.expect()` in `main` causes a panic. The stack trace should give you a hint as to where things went wrong.

## Some debugging tips

### Handle the Err instead of panicking

First, I think you should handle the return value of `mytest()` in the same way that you do the other function that return a `Result`. This could look like the following.

```
fn main() {
    match mytest() {
      Ok(_) => println!("ok!");
      Err(e) => println!("Error: {:?}", e);
    }
}
```

You can of course do something different in each match arm, but it's usually best to not cause your program to panic if possible.

### Tryout the anyhow crate if you're able

Because you're ignoring the errors returned by `.read_line()` and `.parse()`, you're losing context as to where the error lies. The `.with_context()` function can help with this.

Consider structuring your code like the following instead.

```rust
use anyhow::{Context, Result};

fn main() {
    match mytest() {
        Ok(num) => println!("Parsed: {}", num),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
    }
}

fn mytest() -> Result<i8> {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut line: String = String::new();
    match stdin.read_line(&mut line) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => return Err(e).with_context(|| format!("Unexpected failure reading stdin")),
    };
    let num: i8 = match line.parse::<i8>() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(e).with_context(|| format!("Unexpected failure parsing line: {:?}", line))
        }
    };
    return Ok(num);
}
```

Then you will get an error like the following

```
$ cargo run                                                                                          
   Compiling stdin-debug v0.1.0 (/Users/chcl/Development/learning-rust/projects/stdin-debug)         
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.39s                                        
     Running `target/debug/stdin-debug`                                                              
123                                                                                                  
Unexpected failure parsing line: "123\n"                                                             
                                                                                                     
Caused by:                                                                                           
    invalid digit found in string
```

Now it is more obvious where the error lies. The `line` variable contains the newline character! As Ibraheem Ahmed pointed out, you need to `.trim()` line before parsing to ensure it doesn't contain whitespace.

```
diff --git a/src/main.rs b/src/main.rs
index d07677a..4172e4e 100644
--- a/src/main.rs
+++ b/src/main.rs
@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@ fn mytest() -> Result<i8> {
         Ok(_) => {}
         Err(e) => return Err(e).with_context(|| format!("Unexpected failure reading stdin")),
     };
-    let num: i8 = match line.parse::<i8>() {
+    let num: i8 = match line.trim().parse::<i8>() {
         Ok(num) => num,
         Err(e) => {
             return Err(e).with_context(|| format!("Unexpected failure parsing line: {:?}", line))
```

And now I get the following. =D

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling stdin-debug v0.1.0 (/Users/chcl/Development/learning-rust/projects/stdin-debug)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.38s
     Running `target/debug/stdin-debug`
123
Parsed: 123
```

Comment: Doesn't Result require 2 types. I followed the example and got an error thar Result expects 2 type arguments.

Comment: This isn't std's result, this is anyhow's result, which is Result<T,  Anyhow::Error>

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the fact that the `line` variable which contains the user input contains extra whitespace. When you try to parse it into an integer, it fails, and your code panics. You can fix this my trimming the user input:

```rust
// note the use of `.trim()`
let num: i8 = match line.trim().parse::<i8>() {
  Ok(num) => num,
  Err(_) => return Err(myerrors::DownloadError),
};
```

Comment: I changed some unclear aspects in my example. My real case is more complex to show it here. What Should I do if I need to return either value or error?